# MySQL Update Trigger From Null to Not Null

Tags: mysql

I want to detect when a field is updated, including when it goes from not null to null. Is there a better way to do it than the following?

```
If NEW.fieldA <> OLD.fieldA OR (OlD.fieldA IS NULL AND NEW.fieldA IS NOT NULL)
    THEN ...
END IF;
```

It seems overly verbose to do it this way.

UPDATE:
After seeing Mark B's answer below and actually reading the documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to), I got the following to work:

```
IF (SELECT (NEW.fieldA <=> OLD.fieldA) = 0)
    THEN ...
END IF;
```

That still seems a bit convoluted, so I welcome other suggestions...

Why no null-safe 'not-equals' operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [null safe](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) comparison:

```
if new.fieldA <=> old.fieldA
```

Comment: Thanks. This is right, but it still confused me at first because <=> is actually the null-safe equals operator (not the 'not-equals') operator, which I missed because I didn't properly read the documentation.